# nested div doesnt display with javascript in yii

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, yii

I have nested divs  which should display onchange event div abc ,div xyz bt the thng is div abc appears whereas div xyz doesnt . 
both div in

```
 css are dispaly :none

document.getElementById("abc").style.display="block"; ...wrks

 document.getElementById("xyz").style.display="block";.......doesnt wrks
```

bth in same js function triggered onchange event

is it becoz xyz is in abc div n fecth in some other way

abc is displayed with ajax url havng controolerb/actionb.

these divs are placed in controllerA/viewA

```
 <div id="abc">

    <div id="xyz">ghgf</div>

</div>
```

i dont know how do i proceed 
Please guide n letme know move on

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to tell from your post, since there are lot of unexpected contractions, but if that is a literal copy/paste of your code, you are missing a period between your `getElementById("xyz")` call and the `style` attribute. It should read:

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.display="block";
```

Comment: sorry peroid was existing my mistake i hd copy pasted that w/o selecting peiod